# Postgresql server: Allow access to the remote connections within the private network, not external

Tags: database, postgresql, server, remote-access

Presently, I am editing configuration file of the Postgresql for allowing remote connections:

```
>> sudo nano /etc/postgresql/14/main/pg_hba.conf 

#Allout or Universal connection: 
#To all allow all users, from all remote places access 
#to the all databases, add the following to the above script: 
host        all         all         0.0.0.0/0   scram-sha-256
```

How do I limit this access to only to the IPs within our private network. For instance, the range of IP addresses is:

```
1.1.10.0-255, 
1.1.11.0-255, 
1.1.12.0-255,
1.1.13.0-255
```

How to configure the file so the remote connection from any of these IPs is allowed?

Comment: [`host  all  all  1.1.10.0/23  scram-sha-256`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html#EXAMPLE-PG-HBA.CONF)
`host  all  all  1.1.12.0/23  scram-sha-256`

Comment: @Zegarek so, I have to add four lines each for ..10 to 14.?

Comment: You could, but two will be sufficient. See my answer. Also, [here's a calculator](https://jodies.de/ipcalc?host=1.1.12.0&mask1=23&mask2=) you can use for task like this but it's good to have a refresher on networks from time to time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy and modify [an example from the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html#EXAMPLE-PG-HBA.CONF)

```
# Allow any user from any host with IP address 1.1.10-13.x to connect
# to any database.
#
# TYPE  DATABASE  USER  ADDRESS      METHOD
host    all       all   1.1.10.0/23  scram-sha-256
host    all       all   1.1.12.0/23  scram-sha-256
```

The `/23` [netmask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork#Determining_the_network_prefix) lets these two entries enable all four of your ranges:

- `/24` means you accept any number after the last dot in the address (last octet). Your `1.1.10.0-255` in this notation is `1.1.10.0/24`.
- `/23` expands the netmask one bit to the left, so the last bit in the third octet/number can now also have any value. `10` in binary is `00001010` and since you now accept anything on the last position, you also accept `00001011`, decimal `11`. So `1.1.10.0/23` in your notation would be `1.1.10-11.0-255`.
- Same thing for `1.1.12.0/23`. Decimal `12` is binary `00001100`, freeing the last bit enables `00001101`, a decimal `13`. That's `1.1.12-13.0-255` in your notation.

If you also allow `1.1.8.0-255`, `1.1.9.0-255`, `1.1.14.0-255` and `1.1.15.0-255` addresses, you can merge those two entries into a single `1.1.8.0/21`.

Comment: If you don't mind, I used `1.1.10.20/32` to allow a specific IP. Now, I see this `1.1.10.0/23` Can you explain what this `/32` or `/23` mean? How your one line is covering the `1.1.10.0-255, 1.1.11.0-255` IP addresses? Thanks

Comment: The `/23` is a [netmask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork#Determining_the_network_prefix). `1.1.10.0-255` is equivalent to `1.1.10.0/24`. `/23` expands the mask one bit to the left, so `1.1.10.0/23` enables `1.1.10-11.0-255` and `1.1.12.0/23` enables `1.1.12-13.0-255`. Your `/32` covers all four octets of the address, meaning that it'll enable only that one specific address.